# How to perform callback in angular2?

Tags: http, angular

I have the following code in a angular2 **service**:

```ts
this.returned: string;

parseResponse() : void {

 console.log("RESPONSE:",this.returned);

}

sendHttp(text: string): void {

 var to_send = JSON.stringify({"text": text});

 var headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

 this.http
   .post('http://localhost:8080/', 
     to_send, {
       headers: headers
     })
   .map(res => {
       this.parseResponse()
   })
   .subscribe(
     function(response) { console.log("Success Response" + response)},
     function(error) { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
     function() { parseResponse(); }
   );

}
```

but unfortunately `parseResponse()` is not running after my nodejs server returns "testing". However, the request is received correctly. Could you help me please?

### EDIT:

This is the actual code. Nothing is console.logged. The request is sent. No callbacks are executed.

```
parseResponse(res: Response) : void {

 console.log("RESPONSE:",res);

 }

 sendHttp(text: string): void {

 var to_send = "sending";

 var headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

 this.http
   .post('http://localhost:8080/', 
     to_send, {
       headers: headers
     })
   .map((res) => res.json() )
   .subscribe(
     (response) => { console.log("Success Response" + response)},
     (error) => { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
     () => { this.parseResponse(res); }
   );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use arrow functions and prefix your method with `this`:

```
.subscribe(
  (response) => { console.log("Success Response" + response)},
  (error) => { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
  () => { this.parseResponse(); }
);
```

This way you will be able to use lexical this (the instance of the component itself) and reference / call the `parseResponse` method.

See this doc for more details:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this

**Edit**

You need to be aware that when an error occurs in your HTTP request (404 for example), the callback of the `map` operator isn't called. That's the same of the completion callback on subscribe.

Comment: You mean that the method isn't called in the third callback? Is the method called in the `map` callback?

Comment: No. It is not called anywhere.

Comment: You need to be aware that when an error occurs in your HTTP request (404 for example), the callback of the `map` operator isn't called. Is your request successful?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to either pass the response to your method:

```ts
.map(res => this.parseResponse(res))
```

or pass the method reference:

```ts
.map(this.parseResponse)
```

Also your `parseResponse` method should return the "parsed" response:

```ts
parseResponse(res: Response): any{
    let jsonRes = res.json();
    console.log("RESPONSE:", jsonRes);

    return jsonRes;
}
```

Comment: Why does parseResponse have to return the response ? Why can't I handle it all there?

Comment: You don't have to return the response per sé, but the final object you want to get in your subscribe. In my proposed case you'll be returning the deserialized JSON string, supposing your API returns a JSON. That's what the documentation says: `The Map operator applies a function of your choosing to each item emitted by the source Observable, and returns an Observable that emits the results of these function applications.`

Comment: But what is the difference between subscribe and map? I understand the functions but not the context of these in angular 2. What exactly should I put in subscribe?

Comment: In the `map` method you do your deserializing and everything (usually just a `res.json()`) and in the `subscribe` method you're actually retrieving the data stream. Technically you can already store your data in local variables in the `map`method, but you have to call `subscribe` anyway to kick off the HTTP request.

Comment: You don't have the response in the `onDone` callback. But other than that, did you already try the request with Postman or Fiddler, just to check if it's actually returning something?